# PV is greater than /dev/sda2

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, lvm, centos-6

I'm receiving below error. seems like while increase the PV size, I have increased greater than /dev/sda2.Because of which  my root filesystem is corrupted and cannot boot. Also while booting my root password is incorrect.

"Device /dev/sda2 has size of 19945392 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 19945472 sectors. Was device resized? One or more devices used as PVs in VG vg have changed sizes."

I need to boot the fs with password and fix the pv size. 
Please help!
P.S  the disk is not encrypted.